# Does the Paladin count as an adventurer for the purposes of the Magic Key spell?

Tags: dungeon-lords

Do Paladins count as Adventurers?

Year one, I kill the Paladin, and no adventurers.
Year two, the first spell is Magic Key (a slow spell):

> Discard one of your imprisoned adventurers (if you have any).

Assuming I can't kill an adventurer and/or all the magic users, do I lose my first year paladin?

Comment: The Paladin hates it when people lump him in with mere "adventurers" - he thinks he's better than that - but he totally is one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! From the FAQ: [What rules and cards affect the paladin in combat?](http://czechgames.com/en/dungeon-lords/faq/#faq-2374)

> The paladin is still an adventurer, so
>   anything that affects adventurers
>   affects him (including traps and
>   attacks that damage all adventurers).

So in your example, you lose your Paladin. Dungeon Lords is indeed a brutal game...